# ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined Google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

i got this javascript from an API i am trying to query and put it on Google apps script. However i get the ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined error. I googled and saw it is not supported but i could not find a solution on how to bypass it? Any help please?

````
function test (){

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('POST', 'https://api...');

request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log('Status:', this.status);
    console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
  }
};

var body = {
  'channels': [
    '11111111',
    '22222222'
  ],
  'metrics': [
    'post_video_views_10s_organic',
    'post_consumptions_unique'
  ],
  'since': '2017-01-01',
  'until': '2017-03-02',
  'postsSince': '2016-12-24',
  'postsUntil': '2016-12-31',
  'orderBy': 'metrics.post_impressions',
  'direction': 'ASC',
  'limit': 10,
  'offset': 0
};

request.send(JSON.stringify(body));} ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UrlFetchApp instead. 
Here is an example from the site below:

```
// Make a POST request with a JSON payload.
var data = {
  'name': 'Bob Smith',
  'age': 35,
  'pets': ['fido', 'fluffy']
};
var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', options);
```

See here for documentation: [Url Fetch App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)